# the input data is not a complete block. c#

Tags: c#, database, oracle, encryption

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
namespace SOMaintenance.App_Code
{
    public class passwordsecurity
    {

        public string Encrypt(string clearText)
        {
            string EncryptionKey = "SWISSLOGMALAYSIA";
            byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
            using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
            {
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
                encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
                encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                        cs.Close();
                    }
                    clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
                }
            }
            return clearText;
        }

        internal string Decrypt(string cipherText)
        {
            int mod4 = cipherText.Length % 4;
            if (mod4 > 0)
            {
                cipherText += new string('=', 4 - mod4);
            }
            string EncryptionKey = "SWISSLOGMALAYSIA";
            byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
            using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
            {
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
                encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
                encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                        cs.Close();
                    }
                    cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
                }
            }
            return cipherText;
        }
    }
}
```

it throw me an error at `cs.Close();`
the error is The input data is not a complete block..

I am actually doing password ecryption and decryption.
encrypt no problem but when come to decryption, at first it say cant convert from base 64, therefore i added

```
int mod4 = cipherText.Length % 4;
if (mod4 > 0)
{
   cipherText += new string('=', 4 - mod4);
}
```

then it throw me the error I am facing now. hope someone could help me on this. 
Thanks and appreciate

Comment: How does the oracle database come into it?

Comment: because i retrieve from oracle database, and I am not so sure does the data type in database will affect it or not.. at first can't convert from base 64, I am just trying to provide more information for people who could help me..